# Image not downloading - carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

```
Rails 3.2.18
Ruby 2.1.5
```

I am using carrierwave to upload/download images. I am running into a situation where I can upload the document, but when I try to download it, I get the following error message:

```
The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later
```

When I looked through the log file, I saw that the file was supposed to have been sent. The log entry is:

```
Sent file /home/app/uploads/documents/test_document.jpg (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 67.0ms (ActiveRecord: 57.2ms)
```

I checked and /home/app/uploads/documents/test_document.jpg is there and according to the log file, it was sent. Any ideas why I'm getting the error message?

Comment: What happens when you just try to view the image in the browser, by itself? What happens when you write your own htm img tag, and point the src to that image? Are the permissions on the image OK?

Comment: No problem with permissions. I figured out what the problem is though. The file has a file size of 0 bytes. Other images in the same directory download fine. Seems like a carrierwave bug?

Comment: Carrier Wave is pretty widely used and thoroughly tested. It could be a carrier wave bug, but my first assumption would be that it's more likely something wrong within your application.

Comment: All files have no problem with the exception of the 0 size file.